# NSDictionary and NSArray in Plist

Tags: objective-c

I want to do the following:

a plist file with a-z and # for numbers or unknown characters.. so 27 arrays.
I want to store these 27 arrays in a dictionary, a plist file.

It can also happen, that a letter is not represented in the dictionary arrays...

do I need to make 27 arrays and check if they exist or is there an easier way?

I want to display them in a tableview.. all values for key "a" in the "a" section of the table view and such....

Any ideas how I can save time and code?

Thanks for any possibility I can try

Comment: "a plist file with a-z and # for numbers or unknown characters.. so 27 arrays." How did you calculated 27 arrays? Also, can't you use  NSCharacterSet?

Comment: a-z counts 26, and 27th will store numbers and characters, Might be he  has this idea...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this Code

Write Data in pList file

```
    NSString *filePath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

    NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutableArray new];

    for (char value = 'a'; value<='z'; value++) {
        [arr addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",value]];
    }

    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:arr forKey:@"alphabet"];

    [dict writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES]
```

set numberOfSectionsInTableView

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{

return [[dict objectForKey:@"alphabet"]count];
}
```

set numberOfRowsInSection

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

return 1;

}
```

set Cell Text in cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
  [[cell textLabel] setText:[[dict objectForKey:@"alphabet"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
```